# Dealing with a contiguous vector of fixed-size matrices for both storage layouts in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

An external library gives me a raw pointer of `double`s that I want to map to an Eigen type. The raw array is logically a big ordered collection of small dense fixed-size matrices, all of the same size. The main issue is that the small dense matrices may be in row-major or column-major ordering and I want to accommodate them both.

My current approach is as follows. Note that all the entries of a small fixed-size block (in the array of blocks) need to be contiguous in memory.

```
template<int bs, class Mattype>
void block_operation(double *const vals, const int numblocks)
{
    Eigen::Map<Mattype> mappedvals(vals, 
                Mattype::IsRowMajor ? numblocks*bs : bs,
                Mattype::IsRowMajor ? bs : numblocks*bs
            );

    for(int i = 0; i < numblocks; i++)
      if(Mattype::isRowMajor)
          mappedvals.template block<bs,bs>(i*bs,0) = block_operation_rowmajor(mappedvals);
      else
          mappedvals.template block<bs,bs>(0,i*bs) = block_operation_colmajor(mappedvals);
}
```

The calling function first figures out the Mattype (out of 2 options) and then calls the above function with the correct template parameter.

Thus all my algorithms need to be written twice and my code is interspersed with these layout checks. Is there a way to do this in a layout-agnostic way? Keep in mind that this code needs to be as fast as possible.

Ideally, I would `Map` the data just once and use it for all the operations needed. However, the only solution I could come up with was invoking the Map constructor once for every small block, whenever I need to access the block.

```
template<int bs, StorageOptions layout>
inline Map<Matrix<double,bs,bs,layout>> extractBlock(double *const vals, 
                                                     const int bindex)
{
  return Map<Matrix<double,bs,bs,layout>>(vals+bindex*bs*bs);
}
```

Would this function be optimized away to nothing (by a modern compiler like GCC 7.3 or Intel 2017 under `-std=c++14 -O3`), or would I be paying a small penalty every time I invoke this function (once for each block, and there are a LOT of small blocks)? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `extractBlock` is fine, a simpler but somewhat uglier solution is to use a reinterpret cast at the start of `block_operation`:

```
using BlockType = Matrix<double,bs,bs,layout|DontAlign>;
BlockType* blocks = reinterpret_cast<BlockType*>(vals);

for(int i...)
  block[i] = ...;
```

This will work for fixed sizes matrices only. Also note the `DontAlign` which is important unless you can guaranty that `vals` is aligned on a 16 or even 32 bytes depending on the presence of AVX and `bs`.... so just use `DontAlign`!

Comment: Thanks ggael. So there will be no overhead of repeatedly calling the `Map` constructor? 
I'm interested in fixed size blocks only. I need to look into the alignment issue, thanks!

Comment: And thanks for the cast idea. How about the `reinterpret_cast`'s overhead? Because I'll need to call it once per block.

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` should be zero cost. The cost of `block[i]` is the same as calculating `vals+i*bs*bs` (also essentially the same for `mappedvals.template block<bs,bs>(i*bs,0)`). Creating the `Map` from the pointer should be optimized away completely (if everything is inlined).

Comment: ggael I just realized that the `reinterpret_cast` would have to be one just once. That's great. But suppose I have 5x5 blocks and multiply each block by a 5x1 vector. Will the matrix-vector product be vectorized if I use `DontAlign`? I need to target AVX and AVX-512. I realize a 5-vectorization (of `double`s) will under-utilize AVX-512 but something's better than nothing, right?

Comment: `DontAlign` does not disable vectorization, only aligned loads/stores. Check by yourself [there](https://godbolt.org/g/8tEgU7).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot about that website.

Comment: Thanks a lot ggael. I ended up using your reinterpret cast idea. It leads to clean code in my algorithms and it's even slightly faster than my old implementation (using `Map` and separate implementations for row- and column-major), even when `DontAlign` is used. And thanks also for pointing out the alignment issue there.